# Switching between text and HTML editor on Kendo Editor(WYSIWYG)

Tags: kendo-ui

How to switch between the rich-text editor mode and text/HTML editor mode on Kendo Editor?

Comment: What's wrong with the button on the toolbar? Or do you want to do this under your own programmatic control?

Comment: Sometimes the users want to edit the HTML codes generated by the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 2):

The Editor has a built-in `viewHtml` tool, which can be used for raw HTML editing.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#configuration-tools

```
<textarea id="editor">
  &lt;p&gt;I am a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>

<script>
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  tools: [
    "viewHtml"
  ]
});
</script>
```